# Experience with LITEON IT ECT 480 N9S SSDs in high load server?

Tags: ssd, intel

Dell is selling servers with LITEON IT ECT 480 N9S SSDs. I have no experience with LITEON SSDs and can only find very limited information about the LITEONs online.

I have seen the brief fact sheet on the drive, but one thing is the official numbers, another is real-life performance.

Do you use LITEON SSDs in production on high-load servers, and if so, how do they compare to Intel DC drives with regards to performance and longevity?

Comment: Why are you asking the internet? Return the drives and request the SSDs you were expecting.

Comment: Why? Because if they turn out to be better drives I would be OK with it, but I can find no benchmarks of them anywhere. That's why I ask if someone here has experience with that model - or perhaps LITEON SSDs in general.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the data sheets for the two drives:

[Intel S3500](http://ark.intel.com/products/75684/Intel-SSD-DC-S3500-Series-480GB-2_5in-SATA-6Gbs-20nm-MLC)

[LiteOn](http://www.liteonssd.com/datasheet/LiteOn%20N9S%20US%20lores.pdf)

basically the LiteOn drive is slightly less performant, lower numbers in IOPS and Read/Write. Also I don't see write lifetime for the LiteOn, but the Intel is rated at 275TBW.

Generally the Intel looks like a slightly better drive.

That said, if you where expecting Intels and got Liteons you should contact Dell and ask them to ship you the part you ordered.